# If I submit a poster to ICDE, can I submit the full version of paper to another conference?

Tags: conference, paper-submission, poster

I received an opportunity to make a poster submission to ICDE, i.e. IEEE International Conference on Data Engineering. I want to know if I submitted the poster, can I submit the full version of paper, with almost the same content, but much extended, to another conference?

I found a similar question, but I look forward to a detailed answer for my specific question. That question discusses the general case for Computer Science. Its answer says for different domain, the rule is different. I hope to know the rule for ICDE, because the deadline is 4 days later and I have to make a decision on whether submitting the poster. If submitting the poster will disable me to submit the full paper to another conference, then I will cancel the submission. Otherwise I will make the poster submission.

Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: It's not clear what details you think are missing from the answer to the similar question?

Comment: @ff524 I have edited and added the detailed missing information to the question. Thanks.

Comment: If you are not sure whether poster submissions in this conference are published in the proceedings (i.e. which of the cases enumerated in the linked answer applies), check the conference website or ask the organizers. If you don't know the novelty policies of the conference you plan to submit the full version too (which also matter, as per those answers), check their websites or ask organizers. Otherwise, I don't see how that answer fails to address your question. (We don't answer questions about individual conferences here - see the [help/on-topic], bottom section.)